# Odd characters received over serial ☐[J

Tags: java, android, serial-port

I've created a terminal emulator using a library, connect to a serial device with another library and this returns data to my terminal. I can see in the log that every time I write a character in the terminal and sent it over serial, the following three characters are returned along with the correct one. ☐[J. When writing to the terminal these characters do now show up. They are handled in this code in some way but I'm not sure which part, perhaps `doEscRightSquareBracket`:

```
 private void process(byte b, boolean doUTF8) {
        // Let the UTF-8 decoder try to handle it if we're in UTF-8 mode
        if (doUTF8 && mUTF8Mode && handleUTF8Sequence(b)) {
            return;
        }

        // Handle C1 control characters
        if ((b & 0x80) == 0x80 && (b & 0x7f) <= 0x1f) {
            /* ESC ((code & 0x7f) + 0x40) is the two-byte escape sequence
               corresponding to a particular C1 code */
            process((byte) 27, false);
            process((byte) ((b & 0x7f) + 0x40), false);
            return;
        }

        switch (b) {
        case 0: // NUL
            // Do nothing
            break;

        case 7: // BEL
            /* If in an OSC sequence, BEL may terminate a string; otherwise do
             * nothing */
            if (mEscapeState == ESC_RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET) {
                doEscRightSquareBracket(b);
            }
            break;

        case 8: // BS
            setCursorCol(Math.max(0, mCursorCol - 1));
            break;

        case 9: // HT
            // Move to next tab stop, but not past edge of screen
            setCursorCol(nextTabStop(mCursorCol));
            break;

        case 13:
            setCursorCol(0);
            break;

        case 10: // CR
        case 11: // VT
        case 12: // LF
            doLinefeed();
            break;

        case 14: // SO:
            setAltCharSet(true);
            break;

        case 15: // SI:
            setAltCharSet(false);
            break;


        case 24: // CAN
        case 26: // SUB
            if (mEscapeState != ESC_NONE) {
                mEscapeState = ESC_NONE;
                emit((byte) 127);
            }
            break;

        case 27: // ESC
            // Starts an escape sequence unless we're parsing a string
            if (mEscapeState != ESC_RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET) {
                startEscapeSequence(ESC);
            } else {
                doEscRightSquareBracket(b);
            }
            break;

        default:
            mContinueSequence = false;
            switch (mEscapeState) {
            case ESC_NONE:
                if (b >= 32) {
                    emit(b);
                }
                break;

            case ESC:
                doEsc(b);
                break;

            case ESC_POUND:
                doEscPound(b);
                break;

            case ESC_SELECT_LEFT_PAREN:
                doEscSelectLeftParen(b);
                break;

            case ESC_SELECT_RIGHT_PAREN:
                doEscSelectRightParen(b);
                break;

            case ESC_LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET:
                doEscLeftSquareBracket(b); // CSI
                break;

            case ESC_LEFT_SQUARE_BRACKET_QUESTION_MARK:
                doEscLSBQuest(b); // CSI ?
                break;

            case ESC_PERCENT:
                doEscPercent(b);
                break;

            case ESC_RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET:
                doEscRightSquareBracket(b);
                break;

            case ESC_RIGHT_SQUARE_BRACKET_ESC:
                doEscRightSquareBracketEsc(b);
                break;

            default:
                unknownSequence(b);
                break;
            }
            if (!mContinueSequence) {
                mEscapeState = ESC_NONE;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is not a problem with the terminal as it is filtering it. But now I want to write the returned data into an editText and the odd characters are being written. What are they, how do I stop them? They must be some normal case of something that can happen as the terminal filters them out? You can see it here when I am typing exit and it should be mirrored on the right:

[image]

Comment: FYI: `<ESC>[J` is the "[erase](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#erase) down" [VT100 control code](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Comment: Oh thanks! must be that, now to figure out out to stop it showing in the editText.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of escape sequences ;)
see <http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html> for a rather complete list of what you can expect...

Comment: Thanks will have a look, very frustrating trying to stop this!

Comment: It's actually pretty simple to strip these sequences: If you receive an `<ESC>` (`0x1b`) followed by a `'['`, then read (and discard) until you see a letter. All these sequences (with very few and very uncommon exceptions) start with `<ESC>[` and ends with a single letter.

Comment: I could try that then thanks, I notice when I hit delete I get <ESC>[1D<ESC>[J

Answer (score 1):

Esc-[-J is an [ANSI escape code](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php), it instructs the terminal to clear the screen from the cursor down.  The problem with filtering them out is that among these commands many change how the visible text is constructed: they can move the cursor, erase parts, etc.  So, just filtering them out may not give the desired result.  But in this case it just seems like a precaution to make sure that the area where you normally type is cleared.

What I consider the best solution, but quite probably overkill in your case, is to integrate a VT100 interpreter in your program (for example [this one](http://code.google.com/p/zterm/source/browse/trunk/org/zhouer/vt/VT100.java)) that converts a stream of text and command codes into a memory view of the screen, and save that memory.  It will be a perfect representation of what the sending program would like to see on the screen at any time.

Comment: Interesting thank you. Seems like I could edit it out of the library if I found the right piece of code.

Comment: That is the proper way I guess, just overkill for my `editText` and the few commands I want to use it for. Perhaps jsut a regular expression.